# Gerar numero sequencia PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um  banco de dados (MySQL) com uns 100 clientes cadastrados e estou criando uma tabela (ranking) de compras desses clientes, sei que o banco cria um ID autoincrement, gostaria de colocar nessa tabela só os primeiros 20 clientes que compram mais produtos e logo teria o numero de colocação no *ranking* e o nome, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Não vejo porque fechar essa pergunta. Apesar do título ser um tanto genérico, acho que o problema nunca foi abordado por aqui.

Comment: Também acho, mas galera eu consegui fazer, eu fiz o seguinte:  $query_clientes = mysql_query ( "select * from clientes " );
          while ( $cliente = mysql_fetch_array ( $query_clientes ) ) {
           $id_cliente = $cliente['id'];
           $name_cliente = $cliente['name'];
           
           if ($query_clientes){
            $sequencia++;
E deu certo mas desde já muito obrigado pela ajuda...

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Abra a duplicata e você vai entender. Ele postou exatamente a mesma pergunta duas vezes.

Comment: @bfavaretto é verdade, não tinha visto a duplicata.